# grails test-app individual integration test

Tags: grails

How do I execute an individual grails integration test?

*grails test-app com.mytest.UserIntegrationSpec* does not work

I have an integration test called com.mytest.UserIntegrationSpec:

```
package com.mytest

import grails.test.mixin.integration.Integration
import grails.transaction.*
import spock.lang.*

@Integration
@Rollback
class UserIntegrationSpec extends Specification {
:
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

`grails test-app integration: com.mytest.UserIntegrationSpec`.

When executing individual test I use that command and it works.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11760535)

Comment: I've edited my post as an answer because it should be the correct one